# Perform arithmetic operations on null values

Tags: python, pandas

When i am trying to do arithmetic operation including two or more columns facing problem with null values.

One more thing which i want to mention here that i don't want to fill missed/null values.

Actually i want something like 1 + np.nan = 1 but it is giving np.nan. I tried to solve it by np.nansum but it didn't work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4],"b":[1,2,np.nan,np.nan]})
df
Out[6]: 
   a    b    c
0  1  1.0  2.0
1  2  2.0  4.0
2  3  NaN  NaN
3  4  NaN  NaN
```

And,

```
df["d"] = np.nansum([df.a + df.b])
df
Out[13]: 
   a    b    d
0  1  1.0  6.0
1  2  2.0  6.0
2  3  NaN  6.0
3  4  NaN  6.0
```

But i want actually like,

```
df
Out[10]: 
   a    b    c
0  1  1.0  2.0
1  2  2.0  4.0
2  3  NaN  3.0
3  4  NaN  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `np.nansum` here calculated the sum, of the entire column. You do not want that, you probably want to call the `np.nansum` on the two columns, like:

```
df['d'] = np.nansum((df.a, df.b), axis=0)
```

This then yield the expected:

```
>>> df
   a    b    d
0  1  1.0  2.0
1  2  2.0  4.0
2  3  NaN  3.0
3  4  NaN  4.0
```

Comment: Thank You ! 
I am trying to use df['d'] = np.nansum((df.a, df.b), axis=0) code ,but i am getting error . "TypeError: 'axis' is an invalid keyword to ufunc 'exp'"

Comment: @SanniGupta: well that is not in this statement, since this does not use `exp`, likely it is located somewhere elsse.

Comment: a    b    c
0  1  1.0  1.0
1  2  2.0  4.0
2  3  NaN  3.0
3  4  NaN  4.0   want to multiply columns a with column b and generate column c. Any solution for it ?

Comment: @SanniGupta: replace `np.nansum` with `np.nanprod`

Comment: and for subtraction or division ?

Comment: @SanniGupta: for subtraction and division, that is not defined behavior, since there are no *monoids* for *(R, /, ...)* and *(R, -, ...)*. For sum and multiplications, such monoids exist: *(R, +, 0)* and *(R, *, 1)*.

Comment: So how can i proceed same for subtraction or division operation?     a    b    c  d e
0  1  1.0  2.0  1  2
1  2  2.0  4.0 2 2
2  3  NaN  3.0 3 3
3  4  NaN  4.0 4 4

where c = a + b, d = c-b e = c/b
please let me know if you need some more clarification.

Comment: @SanniGupta: what would be the value for the subtraction/division given it is a `NaN`? What would be `2/NaN`? Since division and subtraction have no corresponding monoid algebraic structure (nor in natural, integral or real numbers). It makes no sense. Since the addition and multiplication have a corresponding monoid (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Examples), that means there is an *inherent* unique identity element that we can use.

Comment: So  would you want to say this operation is not possible anyway ? Any possible method which can help me here which one you know ?

Comment: @SanniGupta: it's not about the (non)existance of a method. It is about the fact that in terms of algebraic structures, it makes no sense at all... Why do you think databases have a `Count(..)` and a `Sum(..)` aggregate, but no `Division(..)` aggregate? Because both count and sum can be expressed as monoid foldables: `count = foldr (const (+1)) 0`, and `sum = foldr (+) 0`. For a division there is no foldable. You can devide a column by another, and if one of the two is `NULL`/`NaN` then return `NaN`, but that conflicts here with the question where you want to fill in the identity element.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `DataFrame.sum` over `axis=1`:

```
df['c'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   a    b    c
0  1  1.0  2.0
1  2  2.0  4.0
2  3  NaN  3.0
3  4  NaN  4.0
```